# Purpose of using that after comma

Tags: meaning, grammar, meaning-in-context

> If you answered yes, that you intend to pursue need-based financial
> aid, then you will receive an award letter.

What is the intended use of ***"that"*** after the comma in this sentence? What does it refer to?

Comment: "That" is the yes answer. The sentence is better without the *yes comma*.

Comment: The purpose of comma is to highlight pauses in writing. The writer is, with the comma, telling the reader to take a pause after _yes_. Sans comma, the sentence is just as correct, only that the _parenthetical part_ might perhaps not force itself upon the reader as it does otherwise.

Comment: The commas separate the "parenthetical".  This is a phrase that can be removed from the sentence without changing its syntax or drastically altering its meaning.

Answer (score 1):

I personally think that this comma is intended to prepare the reader for a coming explanation of what has just been said:

> If you answered yes, (***and by answering yes I mean your answer***) that you ***do*** intend to pursue need-based financial aid, then you will receive an award letter.

This additional information could also be put between parentheses:

> If you answered yes *(that you intend to pursue need-based financial aid)*, then you will receive an award letter.

Comment: But as far as I know from the grammar rules, we use “which” for such extra or additional information cases after comma.

Comment: You would say: _If you answered **that** (not which) you intend to pursue something_.

Comment: It's a bog-standard "parenthetical".

Comment: @HotLicks: M, I will definitely google "bog-standard"! Did not know the term :)